# JavaScript in asp:Wizard

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wizard

I am having a wizardcontrol, where in one step the user can input his name, emailaddress, phonenumber etc.

When the user press the "Next" button of the wizard, I'm checking the database to see if there is an excisting account with the specified phonenumber.

If that is the case, the system is supposed to ask the user if he will bind the new information to that number, or if he will enter a new phonenumber.

If he says that he will bind the information, the information is binded and wizard proceeds to step2, and if he will enter a new phonenumber the wizard stays at step1.

The code looks something like this:

```
protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex == 0)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            if (!Mobile_ValidateForExistingUsers(((TextBox)WizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("txtPhone")).Text))
            {
        //JavaScript popup or something, which prompts the user?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where the validater is:

```
protected bool Mobile_ValidateForExistingUsers(string usrPhone)
{
    bool IsValid = false;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCheckMobile", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mobile", usrPhone));

        cmd.Connection.Open();

        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (result == null)
        {
            IsValid = true;
        }
    }
    return IsValid;
}
```

How to ask the user this question, and either proceed or let him enter some new information in a wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most effective way to handle this would be to make the `Mobile_ValidateForExistingUsers(phoneNumber)` function a WebMethod for an AJAX call. Once you write the AJAX code, attach the AJAX call to a `<asp:CustomValidator>` for its client-side validation function and if it returns false, follow up with your `window.alert('use new number')`.

Alternatively, you can handle most of this through server-side code by using a `<asp:CustomValidator>`, although there's no need to set a client-side validation function if you're handling the validation server-side. Simply set the `CustomValidator1.IsValid` property to the results of the `Mobile_ValidateForExistingUsers(phoneNumber)` function and then call `Page.Validate()` to see if the page is still valid. If not, flag a `runat="server"` hidden input and have some client-side code prompt the user on `window.onload` and if they want to use the new number, store that in a second hidden field. Example follows:

```
protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex == 0)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            if (HiddenField2.Value == '')   //Client-side Flag not set
            {
                if (!Mobile_ValidateForExistingUsers(((TextBox)WizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("txtPhone")).Text))
                {
                    CustomValidator1.IsValid = false;   // Invalidate the page so the Next Step fails.
                    HiddenField1.Value = false;         // Page will get re-rendered to client to fix errors and stay on the same step.
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (HiddenField2.Value == 'true')
                {
                    // Use new binding logic.
                }
                else
                {
                    //User does not want to use new number, so logic to handle goes here.
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And then somewhere in the client-side markup:

```
/*
 * Crude example
*/
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        'use strict';
        var hf1 = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
        var hf2 = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField2.ClientID %>');
        var myForm = document.getElementById('<%=Form1.ClientID %>');
        if (hf1.value === 'false') {    // or if (hf1.value) if you just want the truthiness of the value's existence (depending on how you flag stuff)
            hf2.value = window.confirm('Wanna use this number?').toString().toLowerCase();
        }
        myForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps,

Pete